# FormGroup was deprecated in dash-bootstrap-components version 1.0.0

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to copy the exact code [here](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/imohitmayank-jaal).

When I run:

```
from jaal import Jaal
from jaal.datasets import load_got
# load the data
edge_df, node_df = load_got()
# init Jaal and run server
Jaal(edge_df, node_df).plot()
```

The error I get is:

```
FormGroup was deprecated in dash-bootstrap-components version 1.0.0. You are using 1.0.0. For more details please see the migration guide: https://dbc-v1.herokuapp.com/migration-guide/
```

From the migration guide [here](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/migration-guide/), I followed `'pip install "dash-bootstrap-components<1"'`

as suggested, and it installed like this:

```
Collecting dash-bootstrap-components<1
  Downloading dash_bootstrap_components-0.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (197 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 197 kB 2.0 MB/s eta 0:00:01
Requirement already satisfied: dash>=1.9.0 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from dash-bootstrap-components<1) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-compress in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from dash>=1.9.0->dash-bootstrap-components<1) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=1.0.4 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from dash>=1.9.0->dash-bootstrap-components<1) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: dash-core-components==2.0.0 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from dash>=1.9.0->dash-bootstrap-components<1) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: dash-table==5.0.0 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from dash>=1.9.0->dash-bootstrap-components<1) (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: dash-html-components==2.0.0 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from dash>=1.9.0->dash-bootstrap-components<1) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: plotly>=5.0.0 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from dash>=1.9.0->dash-bootstrap-components<1) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask>=1.0.4->dash>=1.9.0->dash-bootstrap-components<1) (0.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask>=1.0.4->dash>=1.9.0->dash-bootstrap-components<1) (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask>=1.0.4->dash>=1.9.0->dash-bootstrap-components<1) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask>=1.0.4->dash>=1.9.0->dash-bootstrap-components<1) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask>=1.0.4->dash>=1.9.0->dash-bootstrap-components<1) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tenacity>=6.2.0 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from plotly>=5.0.0->dash>=1.9.0->dash-bootstrap-components<1) (8.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from plotly>=5.0.0->dash>=1.9.0->dash-bootstrap-components<1) (1.15.0)
Installing collected packages: dash-bootstrap-components
  Attempting uninstall: dash-bootstrap-components
    Found existing installation: dash-bootstrap-components 1.0.0
    Uninstalling dash-bootstrap-components-1.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled dash-bootstrap-components-1.0.0
Successfully installed dash-bootstrap-components-0.13.
```

But then when I rerun the code segment above to build a network, the output is still the same error. I'm using python 3.7.3, knowing that is says that I must use 3.6+. Can anyone explain how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I tried on conda enviroment:

```
conda install -c conda-forge "dash-bootstrap-components<1"
```

and then it's working.